# error: 'bundles of packages are not allowed' when installing GNU octave package in windows 10

Tags: windows, package, installation, octave, gnu

I am trying to install package Spectutils from http://www.music.helsinki.fi/research/spectutils/.

```
pkg install http://www.music.helsinki.fi/research/spectutils/spectutils-3.0.3.tgz
```

results in error

```
bundles of packages are not allowed
error: called from
    install at line 90 column 11
    pkg at line 441 column 9
```

Also tried downloading it and installing from directory like this, results with same error. All other packages results as same error, too. I am on windows 10, with Octave version 5.1.0.

Inside package there is root file and COPY file (.3), which seems fine.

Does anyone know answer for this please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Octave expects a single directory to be within the package tarball, however in this case there is an additional file "./._spectutils-3.0.3" as well.

You need to get the tarball locally, unpack the tarball and recreate it without that file.

Example process in the bash shell:

```
$ wget pkg install http://www.music.helsinki.fi/research/spectutils/spectutils-3.0.3.tgz
$ tar xzvf spectutils-3.0.3.tgz
$ tar czvf spectutils-3.0.3.tgz spectutils-3.0.3
```

Now you should be able to install the local file (assuming octave current directy is where the new tarball is):

```
pkg install spectutils-3.0.3.tgz
```

Comment: It would also be useful if you could let the developer of that package know it is currently not octave compatible. You could point them to this solution.